# add user input to a list in Scala

Tags: list, scala, append

```
import scala.collection.mutable.MutableList  

var x = false
while (!x) {
val list = MutableList[Any]()
val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("input pls:\n")
list += input
if (input == "end"){ x = true ; println("Bye!"); sys.exit}
if (input =="show") {println(list)}

}
```

So whenever I run this program and then enter "show" to print the list it only prints out "show" in the list but why not the other input I have done before? What do I have to change in order to store all the input into my list (append) till i type "show" or "end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is move initialization of `list` variable up:

```
val list = MutableList[Any]()
while (!x) {
    // ...
}
```

The way you have it now, a new list is created in every loop iteration and thus previous content is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Scala 2.11.7 on Ubuntu 15.04 / OpenJDK8

I added a line feed "\n" removal function called `.stripLineEnd` thinking this was needed for the ifs to match, but apparently that is unnecessary and will work fine with or without.

From [Documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps):

> def stripLineEnd: String
>
> Strip trailing line end character
>   from this string if it has one.
>
> A line end character is one of
>
> LF - line feed (0x0A hex)
>
> FF - form feed (0x0C hex)
>
> If a line feed
>   character LF is preceded by a carriage return CR (0x0D hex), the CR
>   character is also stripped (Windows convention).

And, as @Mifeet said, the code was initializing the list on every loop and need to move the initialization to before the loop.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.MutableList  
var x = false
val list = MutableList[Any]()
while (!x) {
    val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("input pls:\n").stripLineEnd
    list += input
    if (input == "end"){ x = true ; println("Bye!"); sys.exit}
    if (input =="show") {println(list)}
}
```